# Instantiating Web Components from JS

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I am trying to instantiate web components directly from Javascript but the system does not find the public constructor. I'll put a simple example to show the context and the results:

HTML Template:

```
<polymer-element name="wc-foo" constructor="Foo" noscript>
    <template>
       Hello World!
    </template>  
</polymer-element>
```

HTML index:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="general/scripts/polymer/polymer.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="...">
</head>

<body>  
</body>

<script>
    console.log (window); // (1)
    console.log (window.Foo); // (2)
    var foo = new Foo (); // (3)
</script>

</html>
```

Console Results:

(1) I have checked the window object and it includes the constructor Foo: function (){return f(a)}
(2) I don't know what but window.Foo returns undefined
(3) ...And so, new Foo() fails: Uncaught ReferenceError: Foo is not defined

Someone can help me to understand whats is the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to wait for the `polymer-ready` event to fire to ensure Polymer has done its setup:

```
document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
  console.log (window.Foo); // (2)
  var foo = new Foo (); // (3)
  console.log(foo)
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/dabaloso/1/edit